# Spring Boot app on Windows 2017 not accessible

Tags: spring-boot, windows-server-2016

I've deployed a Spring Boot application on a Windows 2016 server, but for some reason I am unable to access the application via a browser on either the local machine or remotely.

I have opened port 8080 on the Windows 2016 server, and even resorted to turning the firewall off, but it is still not accessible.

When I start the application, I can see it is running and it is regularly generating an output for scheduled tasks that the application performs. I can also see in the console it shows the following;

```
Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
```

Although it does say something about The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is missing, but I am under the impression that tomcat will still run without it.

There are no other errors in the console that would indicate there is a problem with the application, and it appears to run fine on a Windows 10 machine.

Has anyone has a similar problem, is there some issue with permissions on a server? I have opened a command prompt as administrator and tried to start the application from there, but the result is the same.

A little more information, I have noticed when I execute the command 'netstat -noa' port 8080 listed as 127.0.0.1:8080 has a state of `TIME_WAIT`, I have no idea if that is relevant.

Comment: You tried to curl it for the server host ?

Comment: I have not, the machine doesn't have curl installed and I don't have permissions to install anything on these machines.

Comment: So is there something you can do to check that spring is listening at 8080

Comment: When the application starts, Spring confirms that it is running on port 8080, and the output from netstat is in my original post, showing something is listening on port 8080.